# Voip API - windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-voip

---

Hello folks, 
Is there any VOIP API in windows phone 8 that I can implement in developing an application that needs the voip functionality?

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,
please check this below link.
its great and easy to use.
http://code.google.com/p/boghe/